# is there a way to connect docker to vscode

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

I've a vps sever , and installed linux and docker on it, is there any way to connect the image with my vscode so that if I want to change any thing ,not to rebuild image and reupload it to docker on vps

Comment: (A very typical Docker-oriented development process is to use a local environment without Docker to do actual development; then build an image and do integration testing; then push that image to the production system.  You wouldn't normally make changes directly on the production system, nor would you upload code to the production system separately from the Docker image.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to connect to a Docker container using VS Code. Here is more info https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/devcontainers/attach-container

You can also connect to a Docker container running inside a WSL, by connecting to the WLS instance from VS Code.